# CKEditor Image Plug-In: Possibilities for providing aria-describedby content

Tags: ckeditor, accessibility

I want to allow authors to enter long descriptions in the CKEditor image plug-in dialog, descriptions which then are available to screen readers via the aria-describedby attribute. In our use case, authors work in a WYSIWYG mode; they're not expected to edit raw HTML, so we can't ask them to enter an ID in the image dialog, add a corresponding ID to some other element, etc.

It's a trivial matter to enhance the CKEditor image plug-in dialog to have a field where the author can enter a long description to accompany the short alt description. The result could be something like `<img data-long-description="this is a long description" alt="short description" />`. But what we **need** is `<img aria-describedby="longDescriptionID" alt="short description" />`, where longDescriptionID is the ID of some element on the page (hidden from sighted users or not)....

I have a couple of possibilities in mind. (1) keep the image plug-in doing what it does: output an `<img />` tag, as in the first example, and then some other code in the end user-facing view has the responsibility to find data-long-descriptions, replace them with IDs (randomly generated, say) in an aria-describedby attribute, and somewhere in the view insert corresponding content hidden from visual users, so that screen readers will pick it up.

Possibility (2) is to have the image plug-in output something like `<span class="accessibleImage"><img aria-describedby="randomID1" alt="short description" /><span id="randomID1" class="accessibleLongDescription">This is nice, long description of the image blah blah blah</span></span>`, where .accessibleLongDescription is hidden except to screen readers.

Comment: As someone who implemented CKeditor back in the day and also deals with long descriptions, I think this is a great idea. I am not sure what your question is, though. One thing to share — don't only provide it to screen reader users. Consider maybe a disclosure widget since all users can benefit (think infographics). To that end, I like option #1.

Comment: @aardrian My question wasn't a how-to question. I know how to do both options. It was more of what's a better practice. I also prefer option #1, and that's what I decided to go with, after also talking with some vendors who develop for us. Option #2 feels too -- well, not a hack exactly, but it weds us to having something in our data/content that we might not like later. And we generate A LOT of content. Option #1 offers some separation between the content and the presentation.

Comment: Keen. Do you want feedback as an 'answer' to this (so you can mark it as accepted and/or gather more detail)?

Comment: @aardrian Not sure what to say. I don't think there would be an answer per se but I'd like to get feedback from anyone who has dealt with this type of issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's good that you're looking into this. More detailed descriptions for images are often useful. A couple of thoughts...

It isn't just people who use screen readers that find longer descriptions useful. People with cognitive disabilities will often benefit from more detailed explanations of complex images. If you can make the descriptions available on demand to anyone, this will help more people.

When the description is inserted into the DOM it needs to be immediately after the image it relates to. Screen readers use a translation of the DOM known as the accessibility tree to access content, so DOM order is important.

So one possibility is to combine your methods - search/replace the data attribute as you suggest in your first method, then insert the description based on the pattern in your second method.

Another possibility might be to use a disclosure widget pattern instead. Represent the image as the trigger control for the disclosure, and make the detailed description available when the widget is expanded.

A reasonable [disclosure widget pattern](http://ljwatson.github.io/design-patterns/disclosure-button1/disclosure.html) is here.